# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxxx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, caffe

I'm trying to install caffe in Ubuntu 15.04, but get stuck in the make execution. Here is my command and the results. Can anybody help me out?

```
chauvet@chauvet:~/caffe-master$ make all -j8
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcublas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurand
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudnn
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:563: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like cuDNN is not installed in your system.

Try commenting out the line `USE_CUDNN := 1` in Makefile.config. Do a `make clean` and build the project again.